# How to copy pdf contents to word doc then to excel using excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an requirement, in which i have to open number of invoices in pdf format from certain folder using WORD document to ensure same format as per pdf. Then from word document, i want to copy those contents in excel sheet in same format to ensure tables & columns so that i will perform lot of excel actions from the data pasted in it. So, i want to write a vba to open pdfs using word document and copy paste the contents in excel in the same format.

So far, i have tried only opening one pdf using word document but i am facing error such as "sorry couldn't find your file. is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?". But the pdf file present in the folder. I don't know the exact issue.

```
Sub test()
Dim s As String
Dim path As String
Dim t As Excel.Range
    path = "C:\Users\121919\Desktop\Direct Dispatch Report_PENS\29 Jul\PDF to Word Try\"

s = "C:\Users\121919\Desktop\Direct Dispatch Report_PENS\29 Jul\PDF to Word Try\1151_Odisha.pdf"
Dim wd As New Word.Application
Dim mydoc As Word.document
Set mydoc = Word.Documents.Open(Filename:=s, Format:="PDF Files", ConfirmConversions:=False)
Dim wr As Word.Range
Set wr = mydoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
wr.WholeStory
Set t = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
wr.Copy
t.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
mydoc.Close False
wd.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: What problem are you incurring with the above?

Comment: What line is triggering the error? Does it work using the line that's commented out (`s="C:\...`)?

Comment: I have modified the code a bit. Above seeing code right now is my recent code. It is working fine. Now, my requirement is i have to loop through each pdf in the given folder path and open in word and paste in excel. Either it can paste at the bottom of last filled row or it can copy particular value in excel and then delete the entire sheet content and paste the new pdf content. Requirement is i want to extract LR number in each pdf copied to excel.

Comment: @SathishKumar Well, that will be a separate question